# Meta tag in html

Tags: html

Can anybody tell me that why we use meta tag in html

Comment: Which meta tag are you referring to, you mean the `<meta>` HTML tag in the `<head>` of a document?

Comment: I don't know what we could say that isn't already covered here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element

Comment: A `META` tag is used to describe a `META` element that describes the document.

Comment: Also I made a document about getting better indexed by search engines, it's in Dutch so if you have somebody who can translate I can send it too you. The document is really clear and explains everything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta tags helps your website getting found by search engines like Google, Bing etc.
When you use it the right way in combination with some [landing page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_page) you can get found in the best way. Another method is the use of [link-exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_exchange). If you use the 3 methods it could get your websites way better indexed by google then if you only use the meta-tags.

If you want to know more about it, just search on google with keywords: landing page, indexed by google, meta-tags, link-exchange etc.

Comment: And if you use link-exchange your site might get penalized by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Meta tags describe your page.  Search engines have famously used them to help index your pages.  Its got nothing to do with asp.net but rather the HTML output that is produced.  [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element) for more information.  Be aware although that search engines rely less on them as they do now and incorporate other factors into their indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags are used for many things. The most important use for meta tags would be probably for SEO purposes. The meta description is probably one of the most important parts of the meta tag because that is what shows up under the title on Search Engines such as Google or Yahoo. The following link will give you more information about SEO and how you can use the meta tag. https://blog.kissmetrics.com/website-source-code-seo/

The meta tag can also do many other things such as set the author, viewport and keywords of a web page. Here is a link that will tell you a lot more about what the meta tag is used for. https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_meta.asp